# Why method in in mixin returns object Promise?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In vuejs3 app I want to use common method, so I put it into mixin resources/js/appMixin.js as :

```
export default {

    methods: {

        async getBlockPage(page_slug) {
            const response = await axios.post('/get_block_page', {slug: this.page_slug})
            console.log('response.data.page::')
            console.log(response.data.page) // In the browser console I see this valid page object returned


            return response.data.page;

        }, // getBlockPage() {
```

but calling this method in vue file :

```
mounted() {
    this.about= this.getBlockPage("about");
    console.log('AFTER this.about::') // I DO NOT this output
    console.log(this.about)
},
```

and outputting about var I see

```
"[object Promise]"
```

Which is the valid way?

That question seems a bit specific then provided link, as method is inside of mixin...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure, getBlockPage is an async function, always return Promise.

```
async mounted() {
  this.about= await this.getBlockPage("about");
  console.log(this.about)
},
```

or

```
mounted(){
  this.getBlockPage("about")
    .then(result => {
       console.log(result);
    )
    .catch(error => {
      //error handler
    });
}
```

You can learn more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Async / await is just a syntaxic sugar for define Promise behavior on your function

Comment: Defining  mounted as async ? Could you please explain it?

Comment: It's just an exemple for log the correct this.about value. 
You can also use classic Promise then / catch.

Comment: Could you please give link to  classic Promise then / catch example?

Comment: I have edit the main response